# Visual Studio - Modular control groups in a Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, duplicates, controls

In my project I have the need to create a Form with 16 identical replicas of the same controls. So far I've managed to do this by just copying and pasting the controls and renaming them one by one, however this is becoming really inefficient and I feel like there must be a better method to handle this situation.

Down below there is an example of what I'm talking about: every line has the same controls that are handled exactly the same, have the same Items and only interact with each other within the same line.
Is there a way  to create a modular group of controls that I can replicate and handle with a simple incremental index? The best would be if modifiying the original one would affect every copy of it!

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and C# as programming language.

[image: Example of modular control form]

Comment: Create a [custom control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a custom control as Johnny Mopp suggested (in the comments) was the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of data calls for a DataGridView Control. It supports text, checkbox and combobox "out of the box", and you can add support for Numeric Up/Down Cell as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881%28v=vs.80%29.aspx